# Source Angular Module from different host

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am newbie in AngularJS. I am using requireJS for getting all dependencies in main.js. Someone in my team has shared a module that's hosted on different location. The below snippet file is in main.js on cdn.xx.web.xxx.com/angular/modules/testModule/js/main.js.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');

    var testModule = angular.module('testModule', [])
        .directive('dir1', require('./directives/Directive1'))
        .directive('dir2', require('./directives/Directive2'))
        .directive('dir3', require('./directives/Directive3'))
        .controller('controller', require('./controllers/Controller'));

    // Export the module;
    module.exports = testModule;
});
```

I am trying to use this module in my angular app. I am using requireJS in my controller.

```
 var testModule = require('cdn.xx.web.xxx.com/angular/modules/testModule/js/main')
```

But, this above statement is failing because it's unable to find Directive1, Directive2, Directive3, Controller. I know why it is failing because require( ... main ) statement is trying to look for all directives and controllers in my project directory structure.

How can I make sure that whatever require('') is happening in main.js points to 'cdn.xx.web.xxx.com/angular/modules/testModule/js/', instead of my local project directory structure.

P.S: I have changed the name of Directives and Controllers for some reason.

Comment: The implementation above looks like it's using commonJS "require", not requirejs/AMD "require"; is the project also using a commonJS preprocessor like browserify?

Comment: Yeah, the above module is using commonJS require.

Comment: Any insight on this?

Comment: Do you have a require config object? Where is it? What is baseUrl set to?